# Price Drag Jquery Plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css, interface

I'm trying to find some ideas or maybe answers on what type of plugin is this

http://i255.photobucket.com/albums/hh140/testament1234/Price-Drag_zps78ed315b.jpg

Basically the objective is that user can drag the left icon(Greater than Symbol) and the price below which is zero will change depending on how far the user has dragged the icon.

Answer (score 1):

It is called Range Slider. It is basically a jQuery plugin.

Here is the **[WORKING DEMO](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range)**

In your case, where you have the greater than and lesser than arrows, with CSS, you can change and customize it to meet your requirements.

***PS:You have to yourself customize the defualt range slider with your images, css, etc. to match your design needs.***

Comment: oh i see thanks. Do you have any ideas for a customized range slider just like i posted above. I'm still searching on google for some plugins

Comment: You have to yourself customize the defualt range slider with your images, css, etc. to match your design needs. - @clestcruz